# how to declare and define a time data?

Tags: c++

I have a class that needs to contain a time variable. How to do that? I would like to specify that I communicate with a server and as a response at time section I receive for example: 2011-07-01T14:32:39+02:00 .APPRECIATE. THX

P.S I would like to use the C++ API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several solutions each with another drawback. One would be to just calculate the timestamp and save it as a number. Another would be to use boost date_time (which I would prefer if you can introduce a dependency to boost).
It all very much depends on what you need to do with the time. If you only need to save it and don't need to do calculations on it, may be even a std::string would be good enough. If you need to do very simple operations on it, a timestamp is probably good enough and the simplest way (however you still have the burden to parse it). For complex stuff boost would be my preferred way to go.

Comment: as a client I just want to print the data. But I would like to mention that there is also a posibility for a client to populate the class with the current data time. SO you see I need something that populates the variable from the class with current time as I;ve mentioned in my question and also prints  it.

Answer (score 1):

Go for `boost::posix_time::ptime` if you can use boost, because this is easy to use.

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

using boost::posix_time;
// local time with second precision
ptime currentTime(second_clock::localtime());
// UTC time with second precision
ptime currentTime(second_clock::universal_time());
// local time with microsecond precision
ptime currentTime(microsec_clock::localtime());
// UTC time with microsecond precision
ptime currentTime(microsec_clock::universal_time());
```

For strings you can use the following

```
std::string s = "2011-08-25 23:59:59.000";
// get ptime from a string
ptime t = time_from_string(s);
// get string from ptime
std::string s = to_simple_string(currentTime);
```

For more information, take a look at the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html).

Comment: what is time_from_string(s)? could u please detail ptime t and std::string s?

Comment: is there a way to get time from string and string from time without using boost?

Comment: @sunset: `time_from_string` does what it says. It parses the string into a `ptime` object. For more info check the link I provided. `std::string s` is the resulting string when you convert a `ptime` to a string.

Comment: @sunset: if you don't want to use boost, then macbirdie's answer tells one way to go using the C API. If you tell us about any restrictions in what you can use or want to use it's easier to give an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`tm`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/tm/) struct for holding the time data.

I recently went old school in my otherwise pretty modern C++ project and used [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/) to parse the incoming data strings (from RSS, ATOM), because I didn't want to depend on any OS-specific framework (the app is for Cocoa Touch and Windows) nor introduce Boost dependency. And it performs really great, as always.